# How to get doctrine to generate sql with BIGINT type?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony1

In my schema I have a number of field that need to be `BIGINT`. I use the following command from Symfony

```bash
symfony doctrine:build-sql
```

to generate my database. The fields always come out as type `int`. I have tried the following types in the schema:

- `int`
- `{type: integer, notnull: true}`
- `{type: integer(5), notnull: true}`
- `{type: bigint, notnull: true}`

None of them seem to work (I always rebuild the model before building the SQL).

What type should i put in the `schema.yml`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Symfony 2.x (e.g. Doctrine 2.4.1) and PHP annotations on Entities, using `@ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")` results in a MySQL `bigint(20)`.

NB: OP tagged this question with symfony1 & doctrine1, for which this solution will **not work**.

Comment: The question is about symfony1, with usually uses doctrine1. This should not have been accepted (or even upvoted). It should be a comment

Comment: @greg0ire - you're correct - should have been a comment.  Searching for Symfony2 lands here & I didn't initially notice the symfony1 tag - should probably edit the Q to make that explicit now that most traffic will be concerned with Symfony2+

Comment: Yeah, don't blame the answerer if the question isn't tagged properly!

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel: the symfony2 and doctrine2 have been added by DavidJ 5 jours ago. I don't know why. Look at the [previous revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6019348/revisions) and you'll see that the question was properly tagged. IMHO, DavidJ should rollback his modifications and delete this answer.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your RDBMS, but if you use MySQL, you can read lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DataDict/Mysql.php

```
    case 'integer':
    case 'int':
            if ( ! empty($field['length'])) {
                $length = $field['length'];
                if ($length <= 1) {
                    return 'TINYINT';
                } elseif ($length == 2) {
                    return 'SMALLINT';
                } elseif ($length == 3) {
                    return 'MEDIUMINT';
                } elseif ($length == 4) {
                    return 'INT';
                } elseif ($length > 4) {
                    return 'BIGINT';
                }
            }
            return 'INT';
```

so your second attempt should have worked... or do you use another RDBMS? You should set a breakpoint at this line of code and do step-by-step debugging, this is strange. Also, check the content of your Mysql.php file to see if you have the same thing as me (I use the doctrine shipped with sf 1.4.11)

Answer (score 0):

yes, integer(5) should do the work.

You can check other schema data types in [The symfony and Doctrine book](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files#chapter_04_data_types), but have in mind that it's version 1.2 and it's not maintained anymore.

Best regards.