# Where can I find the setting [key: value] pairs for yaml files to be used in symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, yaml

I have just started learning symfony. Where can I find the settings for defining the table relations and all the switches that I can use for defining the various settings in yml files.

For example:
All the settings that can be given for defining the database (schema.yml)

Settings related to view.yml , what other values and flags can be used.

Comment: found the settings for "schema.yml" on http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en#yaml-schema-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [The symfony Reference Book](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/).

**Update:**

The YAML Schema Files syntax can be found in [Doctrine ORM documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en).

Regards.

Comment: thanks, the settings for "schema.yml" are still not there in that resource.

Comment: yes, you are right. It's strange but this info is hard to find :)
Check my answer on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019348/how-to-get-doctrine-to-generate-sql-with-bigint-type) where you can probably find some more useful stuff.